# how to pair items from two lists

Tags: java, list, lambda, predicate

I have two lists of `ClassA`

```
List<ClassA> list1;

List<ClassA> list2;
```

I want to create 4 lists:

```
List<ClassA> matchedList1;

List<ClassA> matchedList2;

List<ClassA> unmatchedList1;

List<ClassA> unmatchedList2;
```

where `matchedList1` and `matchedList2` contain in order items with same `classA.name` (unique)

`unmatchedList1` and `unmatchedList2` contain in order items that were not paired.

e.g.

```
list1 = name1, name2, name3
list2 = name4, name1, name3

matchedList1 = name1, name3 
matchedList2 = name1, name3 

unmatchedList1 = name2
unmatchedList2 = name4
```

is there any lambda expression to pair items from two lists according to some predicate?

Comment: I think your example should a bit improved..

Answer (score 2):

As you added the `lambda` tag, I suppose that you are ok with Java-8 solution. Note that your `matchedList1` and `unmatchedList1` contain all the elements from the `list1`, so you actually need to partition the `list1` according to the predicate of having the same element in `list2`. This can be done using the `partitioningBy` collector:

```
Map<Boolean, List<ClassA>> map1 = list1.stream().collect(
        Collectors.partitioningBy(e1 -> list2.stream().anyMatch(
                e2 -> e1.name.equals(e2.name))));
List<ClassA> matchedList1 = map1.get(true);
List<ClassA> unmatchedList1 = map1.get(false);
```

You can create `matchedList2` and `unmatchedList2` exactly in the same way:

```
Map<Boolean, List<ClassA>> map2 = list2.stream().collect(
        Collectors.partitioningBy(e2 -> list1.stream().anyMatch(
                e1 -> e1.name.equals(e2.name))));
List<ClassA> matchedList2 = map2.get(true);
List<ClassA> unmatchedList2 = map2.get(false);
```

Note that this solution is not very efficient: its complexity is `O(list1.size()*list2.size())`. If you worry about the efficiency, it's better to build the sets of the names in both lists before.

Alternatively if your lists are pre-sorted by the `name` field, you can use the binary search to speedup the procedure:

```
Comparator<ClassA> comparator = Comparator.comparing(e -> e.name);

Map<Boolean, List<ClassA>> map1 = list1.stream().collect(
    Collectors.partitioningBy(e1 -> Collections.binarySearch(list2, e1, comparator) >= 0));
List<ClassA> matchedList1 = map1.get(true);
List<ClassA> unmatchedList1 = map1.get(false);

Map<Boolean, List<ClassA>> map2 = list2.stream().collect(
    Collectors.partitioningBy(e2 -> Collections.binarySearch(list1, e2, comparator) >= 0));
List<ClassA> matchedList2 = map2.get(true);
List<ClassA> unmatchedList2 = map2.get(false);
```